# How to select the largest percentage change in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, percentage

Suppose my dataframe looks like this:

|  | Mercedes | BMW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 100 | 400 |
| 2011 | 110 | 490 |
| 2012 | 170 | 470 |
| 2013 | 150 | 420 |

I want to find the year and brand with the biggest percentage changes (in absolute value). I know I can do `df.pct_change()` but don't know how to generate the desired output.

The desired output is:

0 BMW 2011

1 Mercedes 2012

2 BMW 2013

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mercedes': [100, 110, 170, 150],
                   'BMW': [400, 490, 470, 420]},
                  index=[2010, 2011, 2012, 2013])

# Calculate percentage change and take absolute value
df = df.pct_change().abs()

# Find the year of maximum percentage change for each column
max_change_year = df.idxmax()
    
# Sort the dataframe by the percentage change
df = df.sort_values(ascending=False)

# Find the year of maximum percentage change for each column
max_change_year = df.idxmax()

# Print the result
for i, (brand, year) in enumerate(max_change_year.items()):
    print(f"{i} {brand}, {year}")
```

Comment: But this will only take the biggest mover for every column once. I want a sorted list of all percentage changes (in absolute value) from largest to smallest, not just for every column.

Comment: I think df.pct_change().abs().unstack().sort_values() works, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
df.pct_change().unstack().sort_values(ascending=False, key=abs)
```

Comment: But this does not result in the desired output from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find brand with biggest change per year using `idmax` with axis = 1:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mercedes': [100, 110, 170, 150],
                   'BMW': [400, 490, 470, 420]},
                  index=[2010, 2011, 2012, 2013])

df = df.pct_change().abs()
df = df.iloc[1: , :]  
df = df.idxmax(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
2011         BMW
2012    Mercedes
2013    Mercedes
```